# MPMoviePlayerController stutter

Tags: iphone, video, media-player

Code :

```
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"m4v"];

   MPMoviePlayerController *video = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]]; 

   [video setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
   video.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill; 

   [[ NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter ] addObserver: self selector: @selector(movieFinishedCallback:) name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object: aVideo ];

   [video play];

....movieFinishedCallback...

   [video release];
```

Result :

Movie starts at frame 10 and then resets to frame 0, creating a stutter effect...

Any Ideas ?

Comment: For anyone else stumbling on this page, I had a similar problem with `MPMoviePlayerController`. The player would restart after about 500 ms, and it would do this about 20% of the time. After lots of time troubleshooting, I just swapped in `AVPlayerViewController` and it's been working great. (`MPMoviePlayerController` is deprecated in iOS9 anyways.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
movieplayer.initialPlaybackTime = -1;
```

Worked for me!  Maybe it wasn't the same problem, but it seems it might help.

Good luck.